# Jenkins not reading ClearCase config spec from file

Tags: jenkins, plugins, clearcase, config-spec

I am using the ClearCase plugin with Jenkins, and am attempting to read a config spec from a file in the ClearCase VOB. The file with the config spec is on the server which Jenkins runs on, and in the build step I ran

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (path\to\file\configSpecTest-2.txt) do echo %%a
```

which prints out the contents of a file, and it successfully prints out the text file. This proves that the path I am using is correct and the server has read access to that file.

Is this a bug with Jenkins?

EDIT: after digging into the documentation, there is a caveat that the file must be reachable by the master node. Does anybody know why this is?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the master node can get the view content, and then pass the content to a slave.

Check if you can configure your Jenkins job in order to perform that step on the master, and not from a slave where the Jenkins ClearCase plugin seems to limit the config spec access.